# “I have made an X to make an X”

Tags: meaning, phrases, sentence-patterns

I have found in a novel the sentence “I have made a call: to make a call.” The context is: the female main character is on the run and distressed, and to try and fix her problems she calls a former fiancé, in a hope to manipulate him.

Is “I have made an X[:] to make an X” a standard phrase? Is it a hidden quotation? Or could it be a play on the different meanings of “call” (phone call, call for help etc.)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a standard phrase or idiom but rather, as you suggest, a play on two different meanings of "make a call." The first use is in the sense of making a decision, and the second in the sense of telephoning someone.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. I didn't get the meaning, specifically of the first half, until you explained it.

Comment: English is not my mother tongue. Is “decision” one of the meanings of “call”? Or is it in the phrase “make a call”? I can't seem to find it in my dictionaries.

Comment: I believe this use of "call" is from sense (i) under the definitions of "call" as a noun found at http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/call: "the selection of a play in [American] football."

Comment: I was looking for some deep psychological meaning - but then we usually just stick to soccer over here.

Comment: @James McLeod: My OED has *Sport. A **decision or ruling** made by an official in a sports contest; the spoken or gestured indication of such a decision. Freq. with qualifying word, as bad (good, etc.) call.* I suspect "selection of a set-piece play" is a later specialised sense for a usage that shares ancestry with, for example, to [call the shots](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/call+the+shots)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - that sounds like a more likely derivation. Either way, I feel it has the connotation of a decision which has to be made quickly, without enough information to be sure of being right.

Comment: @James McLeod: Sometimes. Other times it implies the options are finely balanced even if there's plenty of time - [it was a close call, but after a long debate the jury convicted her](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ytJNRDL0zDgC&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=%22it+was+a+close+call%22&source=bl&ots=WKHavQtJ26&sig=r3WaaJWYNOWvuJJVSDuhdADCCPQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jLJfUM_DD6GS0QXz_ICQCg&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22it%20was%20a%20close%20call%22&f=false)

Comment: @DaG: Yes, that's one of the word's meanings. See meaning #58 at [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/call). (Or, if you'd rather not visit the link, you can just take my word for it – that's your call.)